# LateBinding with dynamic memory

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, late-binding

I have Base and Derive class at the below which related to polymorphism (Latebinding) :

```
 class Base
{
....
};

class Derive:public Base
{
....
};

int main()
{
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  Base *pt;
  pt=new Derive[n];
  
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     pt[i].Input(); 
}
```

While I was inputing the first index of `pt[0]` it's fine, but in `index[1]` the program is forced to close. Any idea why?

Comment: Commenting in your code would help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/proper-inheritance#array-derived-vs-base

Comment: `void main` is not valid in either C or C++. This makes it less easy for people to try your code, and it misleads newbies into an ungood habit. Please don't post code with `void main`. Fixed that for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array of `Base` is not an array of `Derived`. A `Derived` instance can be larger than a `Base`, and then address calculations go haywire when the array is treated as array of `Base`. For this reason the standard specifies **Undefined Behavior** in this case.

Instead you can use an array of pointers to `Base`.

Comment: Sorry you're correct - my answer was wrong. I deleted it and upvoted yours!